# Using CMAKE_AUTOMOC with a custom version of Qt

Tags: qt, cmake, maya, moc

I am developing a plugin for `Maya` which comes with its own custom version of Qt library (including the `moc`). I downloaded the exact `Qt` version `Maya` uses and tried the following:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
```

Now this works but only partially. The plugin causes `Maya` to crash randomly due to (I am assuming) subtle differences in `Maya's` custom `Qt` library vs. the official `Qt` library - even though I have made sure I match the the `Qt` version numbers.

My question then is, can I somehow get `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` to use the `moc.exe` (and others) that ships with Maya instead of `Qt's` own?

Or to phrase the question more generically, **can I get `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` to work with a customized version of Qt and its moc**?

Comment: What makes you think the problem is related to `CMAKE_AUTOMOC`?

Comment: Before blaming others, how do you know the problem is not within your code? Have run Valgrind, GDB and AddressSanitizer?

Comment: @usr1234567 because the crash only happens when I have this code: `        m_button = new QPushButton("MyButton");
        delete m_button;
` if I remove the `delete`, then everything's fine. I have read on this issue elsewhere that `Maya` is running a modified version of the `Qt` library and subtle differences in the binaries will cause these issues.

Comment: @wasthishelpful I didn't say it was...? The problem is with incompatible `Qt` libraries even though they are _officially_ the same version (5.6.1). `Maya` uses a customized version of `Qt` and comes with it's own version of `moc.exe` (and other tools) - that's what I would like `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` to use.

Comment: @usr1234567 I am on Windows. Sadly, there is no Valgrind or Address sanitizers. However, Visual Studio's debugger confirms deleting the widget is causing heap corruption.